# Do I need a certificate of occupancy for each building on a single property?

Tags: code-compliance

If I have 2 buildings located on one property do I need a certificate of occupancy for each building or does 1 certificate cover all buildings?

Comment: Seems like you'd want to tell us where your buildings are.

Answer (score 1):

Check with your local courthouse permit office. In our area you must have a certificate of occupancy for each separate building. The building must pass all inspection requirements and any fines/taxes on the property have to be paid.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the 1) building zone, 2) jurisdiction (city or county), 3) occupancy...office, apartments, retail, etc. (You can’t get one for “single family residential.) (See ICC R110.1)

Check with your local Building Department. They check for fire safety, setback requirements, adequate parking, etc.